# Error: Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular-material

Guys I am new to angular 2 material getting error as shown in image. I tried many options, referred many similar question but nothing worked for me. please help me to solve this issue.

I am trying slide-toggle of angular material. i have added libraries like material, animation, hammer but still getting error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HavRZ.jpg)

```js
/* App Module */

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdCardModule, MdSlideToggleModule, MdTabsModule, MdExpansionModule, MdDialogModule, MdTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdExpansionModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    MdSlideToggleModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



/* App component */

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  color = 'accent';
  checked = false;
  disabled = false;
}

/* main.ts */

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'hammerjs';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

```css
.example-card {
  width: 200px;
}

.example-header-image {
  background-image: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.example-h2 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.example-section {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.example-margin {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Slider configuration</h2>

    <section class="example-section">
      <label class="example-margin">Color:</label>
      <md-radio-group [(ngModel)]="color">
        <md-radio-button class="example-margin" value="primary">
          Primary
        </md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button class="example-margin" value="accent">
          Accent
        </md-radio-button>
        <md-radio-button class="example-margin" value="warn">
          Warn
        </md-radio-button>
      </md-radio-group>
    </section>

    <section class="example-section">
      <md-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</md-checkbox>
    </section>

    <section class="example-section">
      <md-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="disabled">Disabled</md-checkbox>
    </section>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>

<md-card class="result">
  <md-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>

    <section class="example-section">
      <md-slide-toggle
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          [checked]="checked"
          [disabled]="disabled">
        Slide me!
      </md-slide-toggle>
    </section>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Maybe try importing `ReactiveFormsModule` instead?

Comment: no it didn't worked

Comment: Can you show us your angular and angular material versions?

Comment: "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",

Comment: Can you update your dependencies to the latest version by running `npm update`?

Answer (score 0):

hope it'll work. Just remove

```
[(ngModel)]="color"
[(ngModel)]="checked"
[(ngModel)]="disabled"

[color]="color"
[checked]="checked"
[disabled]="disabled"
```

This is because ngModel is not a property of md-radio-group or md-checkbox.